# Calculating the difference in days between 2 dates

Tags: r

I am trying to create a variable "diff_in_days" that calculates the difference between 2 variables using the difftime function:

1. ONSET_DATE and 2) DATE_OF_DEATH

This is the code I currently have:

`humanyr2$diff_in_days<- difftime(humanyr2$DATE_OF_DEATH ,humanyr2$ONSET_DATE , units = c("days"))`

When I run this, I get an error: "Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) :
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"

My date variables are in the format: MM/DD/YYYY

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `lubridate` package with the `ymd()` function:
To make calculations like subtraction with to dates you have to transform to Date class!

```
library(lubridate)

onset_date <- "01-02-2010"
date_of_death <- "23-09-2022"

diff <- dmy(date_of_death) - dmy(onset_date)
diff

Time difference of 4617 days
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to this for all of the observation under onset_date and date_of_death without having to input each date individually?

Comment: Yes sure. This is just an example. If you show part of your data e.g. `dput(head(humanyr2))` we could show how to!

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I used:

`humanyr2$diffdays <- as.numeric(mdy(humanyr2$DATE_OF_DEATH)) - as.numeric(mdy(humanyr2$ONSET_DATE))`

This seems to work really well. Appreciate your help.